# Getting first 10 data after rearranging

Tags: oracle, rownum

I have a table for comments history. I need to select only ten data after rearranging the data (order by clause) based on date (newer to older). May I know how to achieve that? Is that can be done using rownum?

Comment: What's "rearranging" and how do you do this?

Comment: I mean order by clause...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    comment
        ORDER BY
                comment_date DESC
        )
WHERE   rownum <= 10
```